# SN1, SN2 or acid-base reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism, halides, nucleophilic-substitution

[image]

I am asked to give the type of reaction (S<sub>N</sub>1, S<sub>N</sub>2 or acid-base reaction) for the following reactions. I know that both $\ce{MeOH}$ and $\ce{EtOH}$ polar protic solvents, so because the first is an S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction shouldn't the second reaction be that as well? It says that it is an acid-base reaction as $\ce{MeO-}$ reacts with the $\ce{EtOH}$ to from 1-bromopropane, $\ce{MeOH}$ and $\ce{EtO-}$ and then goes on to from a S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction.

I would appreciate if someone could explain why the second reaction would be an acid-base reaction at first instead of a S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction.

Comment: EtO- would be more basic than MeO-...the proton xfer is fast

Comment: **Note**: $\ce{MeO-}$ is a strong base while, $\ce{EtOH}$ is a weak base. My question: how can you perform an acid-base neutralisation reaction then? **+** acid-base neutralistion also produces **water** as a product!

Answer (score 1):

In both cases the alkoxide will be in an equilibrium with the alcohol. This will be occurring on a faster timescale than the substitution but in the first case it's irrelevant as  the same species are present on either side of the equilibrium.

[image]

Methanol is more acidic than ethanol, however, so the reaction lies in favour of methoxide and ethanol.

Comment: But EtOH is in vast excess so you are going to end up with EtO-